# TS5005 When trying to run a SharePoint SPFx webpart from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I get an error when I hit F5 when running a SharePoint SPFx web part in Visual Studio 2015 SP3 but everything works successfully when I use Visual Studio Code   :-

> Error  TS5055  Cannot write file 'C:/XXX/YYY/Documents/SPFx/Projects/WebPartExample1/gulpfile.js' because it would overwrite input file.   TypeScript/JavaScript Virtual Project